# Send message to multiple topics From C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a question that I searched in a lot:
Can we send a message to more than 5 topics at a time? or use "message_ID" to send new message so devices in other topics don't reach the message?

If we have multiple topics in Fire-base project and device exists in lots of topics like 10 different topics then when sending a message to multiple topics using sending API methodology: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
With parameter "condition" that can only send to 5 topics at a time, so, unfortunately, the message reaches the device many times instead of one time (which is what is suppose to happen) when I create multiple messages to send to all topics I have.

Comment: "Can we send a message to more than 5 topics at a time?" It seems you already know that you can send to at most 5 topics in a condition, so I'm not sure what you're still asking here.

Comment: Thank you Frank for asking
I'm sending message to 5 topics using condition yes
But i have multiple devices that exist in more than 10 topics so the message will reach them more than once as it suppose to do
My question is how to send to those devices using the same condition with another attribute or whatever to send the same message only once?

Comment: Consider creating combinatory topics (e.g. a topic `topic1_or_topic2` for folks that want both topic1 and topic2), and then subscribing to that topic too.

Comment: if i can explain it i want with example i will say send to all `US resident` & `all rental houses` & `all car buyers` & etc ...
And suddenly you are in all of these Topics then how i can send the message to you one time only